# Is it possible to add two google Maps API (drawing and geometry) in single html file?

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I wanted Two Google Maps API in single html file. SO I have done like following. But it is not working. Please help me by guiding why I cant and where I am mistaking? 
   Thanks in advance.

```
<html>
     <head>
           <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&libraries=drawing"></script>
           <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=geometry&sensor=false"></script>
     </head>
     <body>
     </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The [documentation is pretty clear on how to use multiple libraries](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/libraries), `To request multiple libraries, separate them with a comma:`,`<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry,places&sensor=true_or_false"></script>`

Comment: Really Sorry, I have not seen the document before. I have studied Google Maps by W3Schools website. Will use it. Thank you so much

Comment: It is always best to look at the actual documentation. If w3shools website doesn't reference it, then it isn't very good.  The [documentation of the v3 API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial) is very complete and includes [examples](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/) of almost everything you need to use it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need two different script links like that. When you want multiple different libraries, you seperate their names with a comma. So use just one script with a single "libraries" parameter like so:

```
 libraries=geometry,drawing
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to see how it is done in the google URL, then here is the example
`<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=drawing,geometry"></script>`